# Facing the challenge while adding the custom styling related to font in the SXA Site

Tags: sxa, media-library

I am building a SXA site and I have created the custom theme by following the [Link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/create-a-custom-theme.html)

I have created my custom stylesheet and added in the theme. But, it is not getting reflected when I preview the site.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the below configurations in place:

1. A page design created for the page and your custom theme is assigned to it.
2. Page design assigned to the page item.
3. Make sure your site's compatible themes settings are proper under the settings item.
4. Make sure your custom CSS file is under the Styles folder of the Theme. SXA loads the CSS files uploaded to the Styles folder.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Anusha for quick response....The above configuration which you mentioned, i have done already and it's up to date. Not reflecting the changes.

Comment: Is it only one particular file which is not loading? Did you try with a different file. Can you post some screenshots which would help find the issue

Comment: The issue has been resolved.... Thanks for you time @Anusha
Actually, i didn't select my custom theme.....while reviewing it, i found the mistake and corrected it.

Comment: One more issue i am facing now.... I exported the site and some modification i did in the index.html file.....now again i am trying to import that file......It is not uploading(taking so much time).
How can we rectify this...

Comment: Are you still facing this issue after you exported and imported back?

Comment: Now it's fixed, Thanks